# Extra space in the label when shrink is true with font size 12px in textfield mui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customize the textField component but I have an issue with the label when it's shrinked:

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import createStyled from "@mui/system/createStyled";
import type { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";

const defaultTheme = createTheme({});
const styled = createStyled({ defaultTheme });

const CustomTextField = styled(TextField)<TextFieldProps>(
  ({ theme, size }) => ({
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      height: size === "small" ? theme.spacing(5) : theme.spacing(6)
    },
    "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
      transform: "translate(14px, 8px) scale(1)"
    },
   "& .MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
      transform: "translate(12px, -9px) scale(0.75)",
      fontSize: "12px",
      fontWeight: 500,
      letterSpacing: 0.6,
      lineHeight: '20px',
      "&.MuiInputLabel-sizeSmall": {
        transform: "translate(12px, -9px) scale(0.75)"
      }
    }
  })
);

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  return (
    <CustomTextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="long"
      variant="outlined"
      size="medium"
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
    />
  );
}
```

There is extra space between the border and the text:
[image: Long Label]

Answer (score 0):

here is a show case for Mui filedSet and legend in TextFiled component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import createStyled from "@mui/system/createStyled";
import type { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";

const defaultTheme = createTheme({});
const styled = createStyled({ defaultTheme });

const CustomTextField = styled(TextField)<TextFieldProps>(
  ({ theme, size }) => ({
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      height: size === "small" ? theme.spacing(5) : theme.spacing(6),
      '& fieldset legend span':{
        opacity:1,
        backgroundColor:'blue',
        marginRight:10,
      }
    },
    "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
      transform: "translate(14px, 8px) scale(1)",
      backgroundColor:'red'
    },
    "& .MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
      transform: "translate(12px, -9px) scale(0.75)",
      "&.MuiInputLabel-sizeSmall": {
        transform: "translate(12px, -9px) scale(0.75)"
      }
    }
  })
);

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  return (
    <CustomTextField
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="long"
      variant="outlined"
      size="medium"
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm using a font-family: futuraBt-medium with font-size 12px and font weight 400 not the standard font

Comment: OK, then you have to check if your `field-set > legend` got the same font or not, you can also fix it by changing the width and maring and padding of the hidden `span` in legends

Comment: I can not give a fixed value for the width because the component is generic and label can differ according to the utility of the component and adding a specific padding works for some label lengths and not for all.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to get the labelInput width and set it for the span width, the current functionalities like `clientWidth` or `offsetWidth` return the content width with padding values and I need only the text width value in pixel.

Comment: You can use the code I just uploaded for changing label width I added color and opacity so you can see what's happening here:

Comment: I added the css styles applied for the legend in my case but I'm using this font family https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/92889/futura-book-bt not the standard one

Comment: Probably the issue with the font-family and the different font size that have the behaviour I have described so far.

Comment: changing the fieldset style does not update any behaviour when I play around with component, I updated my question. I have an extra space now with customized font-size.

Comment: Oh I get it now it's about your fonts but not your font size it's because of those `transform` you put there for your labels but not your `fieldsets` please first remove those 3 `transform` from your code and see if its works, if so you have to add this transforms to you fieldset lagend or span

Comment: even by removing the `transform` the space still exists in the input label and I think it an issue in mui according to that link https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/19409#issuecomment-581904964

Comment: it's mentioned that if fixed but I'm not sure that works correctly.